# Query on top N rows in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to fetch 100 records from a student collection sort by name. Now i want to get student who has marks greater than x in this 100 records only. Can any one please help in solving this. When i give Max(marks) in query it is executing before the sort and skip.

This the query i tried

```
var query = {};
query["marks"] = {$gt:35};
db.collection("student").find(query).skip(0).limit(100).sort("name")
```

Comment: Please post sample documents and the queries you tried.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When your query is described in steps as in this case, the ability of `aggregate` to pipeline results from the output of one operation to the input of the next makes it a natural choice:

```js
db.student.aggregate([
    // First sort all the docs by name
    {$sort: {name: 1}},
    // Take the first 100 of those
    {$limit: 100},
    // Of those, take only ones where marks > 35
    {$match: {marks: {$gt: 35}}}
])
```

Comment: Is there any way i can pass query to it like {"name":"Kishore"}

Comment: @kishore Sure, you would add `{$match: {name: "Kishore"}}` to your pipeline for that.  See docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Comment: i got it thanx for saving my time.

Comment: actually i specified two match queries one before sort and one at last and it served my purpose exactly

Comment: sorry to disturb again, last question is there a way to specify sort inside match.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this by applying your condition on the cursor.
So first select the rows from database and then apply the condition on cursor returned by find query.

```
   db.student.find().limit(100).sort({"name":1}).forEach( function(doc){ 
                                       if(doc.marks >35) { print(doc.marks); } 
                                                 });
```

or

```
    var cursor = db.student.find().limit(100).sort({"name":1});
    cursor.forEach(function(doc){ if(doc.marks >35){ print(doc.marks); } } );
```

These above queries are doing same thing. They will first fetch the records from the database and then will print marks of all the documents which have marks greater then 35.

Comment: This would be an inefficient solution that requires all documents to be sent back to the client to be matched.